# GeoPandas sjoin returning fewer records than expected

Tags: geopandas

I used GeoPandas sjoin() to merge two Geodataframes. The first one contains 15kk records of buildings and the second one contains all parts of ortofotomap of my country. I have got layer which contains 11.2kk records but I should get the same like the first layer. I was thinking about that and the problem could be when some building stands on 2 parts of map.

What if building stands on 2 parts of map?

Will the code return 2 records, 1, the newest or nothing?

I would like to get 4 records if buildings stands on 4 parts of map because it is possible. For example building can stand in a corner of every from 4 parts of map.

Maybe I should add some argument?

Code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
    

bud = gpd.read_file('/home/gis/budynkipolska/output.shp')
kaf = gpd.read_file('/home/gis/completed_kafs.shp')

kaf_bud_join = gpd.sjoin(bud, kaf)
```

Comment: What if you try `kaf_bud_join = gpd.sjoin(bud, kaf, how='left')` because the default value is `'inner'` for the `how` argument, see [documentation](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas-sjoin).

Comment: Have you read the comments in your many deleted questions ? Without details, it is impossible to answer

Comment: You don't need more details in this case.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I personally cannot understand. For example:  What do you mean by *I should get the same like the first layer*? And *the newest*, what does it mean? Also, what do you mean by *map*, a layer or all layers? How many layers are there, two or three?